# Examples for $A \otimes_R B \ne A \otimes_\Bbb{Z} B$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I saw the question [Is my example correct? $A \otimes_R B \ne A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155039/is-my-example-correct-a-otimes-r-b-ne-a-otimes-mathbbz-b) and the answer is wonderful.

I am wondering is there any examples without $A \otimes_R B = 0$? Because when I was doing the exercise, I took any commutative ring $R$ and Abelian group $A$ and define the multiplication always being 0. Then $A \otimes_R A$ seems to be an example too. Or is my trivial example wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: don't forget that $\mathbb Z$ does not act as $0$ on $A$, unless $A=0$.

Comment: @peterag Thanks. I forgot the axiom $1\cdot x = x$. I am totally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=\Bbb Z[i]$. Then $R\otimes_R R \cong R$ has rank two as a $\Bbb Z$-module, whereas $R \otimes_{\Bbb Z} R$ has rank four.

Comment: Thanks! It is a great example. Is my trivial example correct?

Comment: More generally, $A=B=R$ being a free abelian group of rank $>1$ works, for example, $R=\mathbb Z^2$.